to dynamically use 2 servers by using parameter in data source
I want to use a parameter for the user to select from 2 servers but I am facing issues with this.
I used the solution: Dynamically set the data source for SSRS reports without unattended execution account?
but it didn't work and this is my error.
error
="Data Source="+Parameters!ReportParamEnvironment.Value+"; Initial Catalog=ReportServer"
I have tried both + and & but its the same error.
Parameter:(https://i.sstatic.net/6Jeob.png), no default values in the parameter
Would be really helpful to understand why there is an error. Thanks!

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

First, start by hardcoding to connection string to one of your servers. Test with this to make sure the connection string is all in the correct format. Next, swap out parts of the connection string for your report parameters. You can also add another parameter that uses the same expression as you connection string so you can see exactly what the generated conn string looks like. That should help you track down the real issue.
